# Determine if the function is increasing or decreasing

Tags: analysis, supremum-and-infimum

I want to determine if the function $\{nsin\frac{1}{n}\}^{\inf}_{n=1}$ is **increasing** or **decreasing**, in order to find supremum and infimum (and decide if maximum and minimum exist).

So the first thing I have to do to be able to decide supremum, infimum and if max and min exist is to find out if the function is increasing or decreasing but how do I do this without using my graphing calculator? My first thought was to find the zeros for the derivative and check this but there are no zeros for the derivative (or at least that could not be found with a calculator).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show that $0\le\frac{\sin x}x\le 1$ for all $x>0$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin x}x = 1$ to get the supremum (it's one).

Comment: Thank you @amsmath. But doesn't it also have a minimum/infimum? That in this case should be sin(1)?

Comment: This function has increasing and decreasing intervals. It is odd, so let's look only to positive arguments. the supremum is $1$ as limit at infinity and the infimum, it is also the minimum, is first negative local mimimum after the most big zero in $\frac{1}{\pi}$.

Comment: @zkutch "It is odd" - No, actually, it's even.

Comment: @kabin Yes, it's minimum is at $n=1$ because the sequence is increasing.

Comment: Sure,  @amsmath - I forget to check English word - looking only positive arguments not changes, right? Btw, I spoke about $x\sin\frac{1}{x}$.